# Networking - Lost wifi connection on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking

I have lost wifi connection on my computer running Ubuntu 20.04 - The wifi was working fine yesterday, but after turning the computer on today it seems to not be able to connect the USB adapter. In the GUI Network Settings there is "wired" (cable unplugged), VPN, and Network Proxy, none of which are connected. Putting `sudo lshw -c network` into the terminal brings up the wireless adapter and the driver r8169, so they are both connected. How do I connect the adapter to the internet again? (The internet in the house is working fine and other devices are connected to it)

`lsusb` gives:

```
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB3.0 802.11ac 1200M Adapter
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command. `r8169` is not a wireless adapter.

Comment: Nothing happens with that command? The adapter itself is "Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller" and under "configuration" it says "```driver=r8169 driverversion=5.8.0-36-generic firmware=rtl8168f-1_0.0.5 06/18/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII```" That's why I thought the driver was r8169, is that not right?

Comment: Ethernet is not a wireless adapter. Are you using a USB dongle? It is unclear what kind of wireless adapter you are using. But the issue is related to upgrading kernel to 5.8. You can boot with a previous kernel using grub menu.

Comment: Yes! Sorry if that was unclear, I don't know the right words for things lol

Comment: Ethernet is a wired adapter.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realise it had updated. I'll try going back to the older kernel

Comment: But it is better to find out what is the problem. So what is the adapter? I is it a USB one. if not, what does `lspci` show?

Comment: Changing the kernel worked, thank you so much! It's a Realtek USB adapter/dongle. `lspci` gives: `02:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042 SuperSpeed USB Host Controller
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 09)`

Comment: Hahaha sorry! I was struggling to understand what you meant. I'll edit that in!

Comment: It is rtl8812bu. You probably installed a driver for it from somewhere. Please add information about it to your question. You either installed the driver a wrong way (without dkms), of the driver is no good for this kernel, so you need to find another one.

Comment: Thank you! I'm currently looking for a new driver lol

Answer (score -1):

If you didn't update any drivers/Update and you didn't change any BIOS parameter then I would suggest to:

- Make sure you didn't update your Kernel or Ubuntu updated silently your Kernel or drivers. (In the comments the user acknowledges that was the reason)
- Poweroff and Poweron (I know, but many many times this works)
- Make sure the Ethernet dongle is not connected to a USB switch, connect directly to a USB or USB-C in the laptop
- Try to connect it to another Wifi USB dongle in the laptop. There are cheap ones from around $14 USD.

Please list what you see executing:

```
lsusb
```

Did you install any Software that can interfere? (VirtualBox, Docker...)

Please, try it connected to the power, not just using the battery to discard that power management control is not interferring.

Cheers

Comment: Obviously some driver for the dongle didn't build with the new 5.8 kernel. So what is the point of powering on, off, etc?

Comment: The user has not reported which Kernel and neither talked about updating. He said yesterday was working and today not. Which Kernel is using cannot be guessed by your superpowers, and is not obvious if there is a bug. Specially when is not mentioning having done anything new since the previous day when it was working. Why you downvoted my answer and then you added a comment later suggesting to use lsusb as I suggested?. If you don't understand why I suggest a solution, when I'm trying to help, at least don't troll. Thanks.

Comment: The user has already replied that all works with a previous kernel. And you can see that I asked for `lsusb` long before you posted this answer ;-)

Comment: When I checked this ticket the comment indicating that the Kernel was updated and the user didn't realize didn't exist. So I tried to help with the existing information. Reloading and expanding the new comments can be seen. If you check the post dates, I mentioned lsusb before you, at least that is being reported by askubuntu. I don't see the point in your reaction and negative score demotivating contributors. The page should be more dynamic indicating updates while one is editing an answer. As it takes time doing.

Comment: Anyway this answer is not useful in its current state.